# Erros shows xml how to fix it

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I don't know why when I run it works fine but shows these red lines on every XML it defaults me to add new widgets
[image: check]

anyone knows how to fix it in this image you can check what I want to say

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: check image please

Comment: Learn How to ask questions on stackoverflow before asking :- follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: move your cursor above the error it will show what is the error or click on File and Invalidate Caches

Comment: It works fine when i change the package name all XML shows this

Comment: when I run the app runs normally there is no issue in-app code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalidate Cache and Restart & click check box checked your issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

It may repeat periodically but solution is

```
clean Project 

Rebuild Project
```

and

```
Invalidate Cache and Restart
```

Answer (score 0):

in android studio, in top view, select "build" option  -> select "clean project" it will clear errors